# ¿Cómo se pasa un array como parámetro en una consulta de API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

Me gustaria consultar [una API](https://apidoc.pulsarplatform.com/#tag/REST-API-v3-Results/paths/~1api~1v3~1trac~1results~1%7Bid%7D/get) y poner varios elementos en el parametro `fields` de la pipeline para que parecen a

```
https://demo.pulsarplatform.com/api/v3/trac/results/query_code?fields[]=content&fields[]=reaction_count&fields[]=sentiment
```

Intento :

```
def load_topics(entity, start_date):
    aut_token = "my_aut_token"
    url = 'https://demo.pulsarplatform.com/'
    api_results = 'api/v3/trac/results/' 
    query_code = 'query_code' 
    search_api_url = url + api_results + query_code
    headers = {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': aut_token
    }

    if start_date == '1577836800' # unix format

    params = {

            'date_from': start_date,
            'fields[]': 'topics', 
            'fields[]': 'sentiment'
    }
    response = requests.get(
            search_api_url, headers=headers, params=params
    )

    # print("requests.prepare(): ", req.prepare())
    json = response.json()


    return json
```

Sin embargo sólo se tiene en cuenta el último, `'fields[]': 'sentiment'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que `params`  es un diccionario y las claves de un diccionario son únicas, si reusas una clave solo la última asignación queda en el diccionario. Puedes pasar una lista con los valores del parámetro a la clave:

```
params = {
    'date_from': start_date,
    'fields[]': ['topics', 'sentiment']  
    }
```

Alternativamente puedes usar una lista de tuplas en vez de un diccionario:

```
params = [
    ('date_from', start_date),
    ('fields[]', 'topics'), 
    ('fields[]', 'sentiment')
    ]
```